# How to change webform default email address from sender side?

Tags: 7, webforms, emails

I'm using webform module, when somebody submits the form mails will go from address which we mentioned in the custom field, this works fine.

But instead of adding in custom field, I want to change the default from email address. Is there any way to do this?

For reference follow this image: [image]

Comment: maybe in `/admin/config/system/site-information`

Comment: No, site email address is different, not this one. In webform module only they have embedded i guess. but i dont know how to change that one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can usually find a configure link in the module list.

[image]

Looks like in `/admin/config/content/webform`

and scroll down to default e-mail values.

[image]

(For Drupal 6, go to yoursite.com/admin/settings/webform)

Comment: I have upvoted, bcz of i dont have 50reputations, it may appear later i guess..